# Pandas - Select rows from a dataframe based on list in a column

Tags: python, pandas

This thread [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas) shows how you can select rows if the column contains a scalar. How can I do so if my column contains a list of varied length?

To make it simple, assume the values in the list are similar.

```
           label
0          [1]
1          [1]
2          [1]
3          [1]
4          [1]
5          [1]
6          [1]
7          [1]
8          [1]
9          [1]
10         [1]
11         [1]
12         [1]
13         [1]
14         [1]
15         [1]
16         [0,0,0]
17         [1]
18         [1]
19         [1]
20         [1]
21         [1]
22         [1]
23         [1]
24         [1]
25         [1]
26         [1]
27      [1, 1]
28      [1, 1]
29      [0, 0]
```

I tried the following which does not work. What I tried was to check if the last element of the list is equivalent to a scalar.

```
df_pos = df[df["label"][-1] == 1]
```

Using `tolist()[-1]` returns me only the last row.

```
df_pos = df[df["label"].tolist()[-1] == 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `str`

```
df_pos = df[df["label"].str[-1] == 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a new column:

`df['label2'] = df['label'].apply(lambda x: x[0])`

and then do the operations on the column label2

Answer (score 0):

Today, I have worked on a similar problem where I need to fetch rows containing a value we are looking for, but the data frame's columns' values are in the list format.

This is the solution I have come up with.

`fetched_rows = df.loc [ df['column_name'].map( lambda  x : True if check_element in x else False) ==  True ]`

Where column_name ---> the column name that we need to look into

check_element ---> the value that we use to check whether it exists.